# Getting 1000 latest tweets and writing it into a log file

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

i have been trying to get the latest 1000 tweets. I have read all the documentation on LinqToTwitter. I tried writing my own:

```
 void GetUserTimeLine(TwitterContext ctx)
     {
        List<String> tweetList = new List<String>();
        String[] breakWords;
        ulong maxID = 0000;
        ulong sinceID = 3396455589; //oldest tweetID
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                var statusTweets =
               from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
               where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                     tweet.Count == 200 &&
                     tweet.SinceID == sinceID &&
                     tweet.ScreenName == "nyptweets"
               select tweet;



                tweetList.Add(statusTweets.ToList().ToString());
                breakWords = tweetList[tweetList.Count - 1].Split(' ');
                maxID = Convert.ToUInt64(breakWords[5].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                var statusTweets =
               from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
               where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                     tweet.Count == 200 &&
                     tweet.SinceID == sinceID &&
                     tweet.MaxID == maxID &&
                     tweet.ScreenName == "nyptweets"
               select tweet;
               tweetList.Add(statusTweets.ToList().ToString());
               breakWords = tweetList[tweetList.Count - 1].Split(' ');
               maxID = Convert.ToUInt64(breakWords[5].ToString());
            }


        }
       string dwnloadFilePath = @"C:\temp\Tweet.log";

        // CREATE AN EMPTY TEXT FILE
        FileStream fs1 = null;
        if (!File.Exists(dwnloadFilePath))
        {
            using (fs1 = File.Create(dwnloadFilePath)) ;
        }

        // WRITE DATA INTO TEXT FILE
        if (File.Exists(dwnloadFilePath))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dwnloadFilePath))
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(dwnloadFilePath, tweetList);
             }
          }
       }
```

Can someone help me with that? The problem is that when I select a single tweet it is not a `string` therefore when I add it to the `List<string>` it doesn't work.

Comment: What *is* a single tweet defined as, is it a object? perhaps a JSON object? Could you maybe debug/watch and post what type of object it is.

Comment: I don't get your problem, and I guess you don't get it yourself either, debug this please and only include the relevant part of the code instead of a big long function (perhaps split it up? functions longer than a few lines are ugly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of it, you should consider cleaning up your code like so (half the length):

```
public class Twitter
{
    private List<String> tweetList;
    private String[] breakWords;
    private ulong maxID = 0000;
    private ulong sinceID = 3396455589; //oldest tweetID

    private void progressTweet(int i)
    {
        var statusTweets =
               from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
               where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                     tweet.Count == 200 &&
                     tweet.SinceID == sinceID &&
                     tweet.ScreenName == "nyptweets"
               select tweet;

        if (i == 0)
            tweetList.Add(statusTweets.ToList().ToString());
        else
            tweetList.Add(statusTweets.Where(x => x.MaxID == maxID).ToList().ToString());

        breakWords = tweetList[tweetList.Count - 1].Split(' ');
        maxID = Convert.ToUInt64(breakWords[5].ToString());
    }

    void GetUserTimeLine(TwitterContext ctx)
    {
        tweetList = new List<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            progressTweet(i);

        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\Tweet.log", tweetList);
    }
}
```

Noticeable is that you don't use `i` other than for the `if (i == 0) ... else ...` which doesn't look quite right to me, other than that another optimization is to not run the LINQ for each iteration but rather select those that you want in advance, so that you can pass on actual tweets to `progressTweet`.

As to keep this an actual answer, I don't expect `.ToList().ToString()` to be right.

Comment: I shall try yours right away. Btw i need to write return result of the request to a log file. For example, Tweets.log. I do not know how to write var StatusTweets as a List<String> or other possible data type into a log file. Any advice?

Comment: Enumerate over the list and print the individual entries?

Comment: Tom i think what u are suggesting is what i want. After googleing and try it on my own, i still unable to print individual entries out to a text file. mind if you can help me with a sample?

Comment: @10e5x: What part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: Enumerate over the list and printing the individual entries. I do not uds how to hand statusTweet. I believe it is either an IEnumerable object or is some kind of object which i dont uds. From the debug mode, i keep get the type LinqToTwitter. i tot that is the api i am using?

Comment: @10e5x: I see from the other comment thread that you can't get `File.WriteAllLines` to work, why not try to manually write to a file instead? And yes, you need to get your data from that `LinqToTwitter`.

Comment: to be honest, i just learnt C# not long. Used to vb.net. From what i know, i will be able to use streamwriter or system.io. However the problem now is i do not know how to get the single tweet it returns me. When i debug and hover over, it only show me funny things. i do not enough reputation to move this to a chat, do u mind?

Comment: @10e5x: Try to understand those funny things, look up documentation on the APIs you are using.

Comment: Ok tom, thanks for being so helpful. By hook or by crook i have to get this done today. thanks for all the advice. i have decided to scrap what i have done and start from the beginning again. Really appreciate your help. Stack is really a very wonderful platform, but i guess not really for beginners. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the library you are using, but you see the code section where there are `tweet.Type`, `tweet.Count`, etc... there has to be a member called "Description", or "Body" or "Content". Intellisense should be able to help you with that (pressing tweet. should expand a list of what you can do with the object). Knowing this, you can now construct the string you want to store in the list (by iterating on all objects in `statusTweets`), probably something like the username and the tweet body?

ToString is an operator that, when not defined, will simply output the object type as a string, which is not what you want.

Comment: You are correct. Slogging my way for a solution for that. Discarding the method i was using and trying other ways. I just simply pass IEnumberable object as parameter and write each lines to text file...

Answer (score 0):

If you need latest 1000 rows, why don't you try Take(1000) order by tweek date descending.

It goes like this

```
    var latestTweets= (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                   where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                         tweet.Count == 200 &&
                         tweet.SinceID == sinceID &&
                         tweet.ScreenName == "nyptweets"
                       orderby <tweet.tweetdate> descending
                   select tweet).Take(1000);

foreach(var tweet in latestTweets){
 // Work on each tweet object.
}
```

Comment: If this works, u are my life saver. Let me go try. Btw if your method works, i how can i write latestTweets into a log file? any advice?

Comment: Above query will return an IEnumerable of type tweet. Updated my answer to iterate through the result set.

Comment: Hi Naresh, thanks for the reply. You have been very helpful. My method really returns me an IEnumerable of an object. Is it possible if i use your method, and it will write it into a text file? I was using file.writealllines but i does not allow IEnumerable. Please advice me

Comment: Hi Naresh to be fair to other readers, i tried your method before discarding my prog and start from the beginning again. Sorry to say it does not work, i still returns me the latest 200. Thanks for your help anyway.